# unique_ptr is not getting init with default deleter

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers

When I create an `unique_ptr` with `deleter`, it works:

```
std::unique_ptr<Animal<Cat>, void(*)(Animal<Cat>*)> ptr(new Animal<Cat>, [](Animal<Cat> *ls) {
    delete ls;
});
```

But, this code is throwing error:

```
std::unique_ptr<Animal<Cat>, void(*)(Animal<Cat>*)> ptr;
ptr = std::unique_ptr<Animal<Cat>, void(*)(Animal<Cat>*)>(new Animal<Cat>, [](Animal<Cat> *ls) {
    delete ls;
});
```

The error:

```
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:2561:13: error: static_assert failed "unique_ptr constructed with null function pointer deleter"
                static_assert(!is_pointer<deleter_type>::value,
                ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
note: in instantiation of member function 'std::__1::unique_ptr<Animal<Cat>, void (*)(Animal<Cat> *)>::unique_ptr' requested here
            std::unique_ptr<Animal<Cat>, void(*)(Animal<Cat>*)> ptr;
                                                                ^
```

This is my compiler version:

```
Apple clang version 4.0 (tags/Apple/clang-421.0.60) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin12.4.0
Thread model: posix
```

The Animal and Cat classes are trivial. [This is the entire code](http://ideone.com/7vgLPH).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It as apparently not possible to default-construct a `unique_ptr` with a pointer type for a deleter. The `unique_ptr` constructors are detailed in §20.7.1.2.1 [unique.ptr.single.ctor] which says, among other things:

> `constexpr unique_ptr() noexcept;`
>
> 4 *Remarks*: If this constructor is instantiated with a pointer type or reference type for the template
>   argument `D` [the deleter type], the program is ill-formed.

Something similar to what you want that is standard conforming:

```
unique_ptr<int, void(*)(int*)> ptr{nullptr,[](int*p){delete p;}};
// ...
ptr.reset(new int(42));
```

Answer (score 11):

After reading Casey's answer above, I changed my code to use good old Functors instead of lambda to make it work.

This is my solution:

```
struct Deleter {
    void operator()(Animal<Cat>* ls) {
        delete ls;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Animal<Cat>, Deleter> ptr;
    ptr = std::unique_ptr<Animal<Cat>, Deleter>(new Animal<Cat>);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The rationale for this `unique_ptr` behavior is to try to inform you at compile time that a null pointer-to-function is not a good deleter.    You can override this behavior by explicitly sending in a nullptr deleter.  But the solution you chose instead is better imho.

Comment: @HowardHinnant Will it check for nullptr at runtime or will it try to call that function?

Comment: @user877329: If `~unique_ptr()` or `reset()` is called and `get_deleter()(get())` is not well formed, you get undefined behavior.

Comment: @HowardHinnant If the old pointer was non-empty, deletes the previously managed object `if(old_ptr != nullptr) get_deleter()(old_ptr)`. It looks like it is safe to set it to whatever as long as the pointer is nullptr.

Comment: @user877329:  Agreed.  Your point is arguably a defect in the standard which requires the expression to be well-formed whether or not `get() == nullptr`.  Here is how you can make the standard better: http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#submit_issue  :-)